# Отрицательные значения margin

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте. Код на ссылающуюся таблицу из текста выше:

```css
 :root {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    *,
    ::before,
    ::after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    /* Код */
    body {
      background-color: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    header {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #0072b0;
      border-radius: .5em;
    }

    .container {
      display: table;
      border-spacing: 1em 0;
    }

    .main {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 70%;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: .5em;
    }

    .sidebar {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 30%;
      padding: 1.5em;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: .5em;
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Franklin Running Club</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <main class="main">
      <h2>Come join us!</h2>
      <p>
        The Franklin Running club meets at 6:00pm every Thursday
        at the town square. Runs are three to five miles, at your
        own pace.
      </p>
    </main>
    <aside class="sidebar">
      <div class="widget"></div>
      <div class="widget"></div>
      <div class="gizmo"></div>
    </aside>
  </div>
```

При добавлении отрицательных полей таблице ничего не происходит

Comment: У вас не блочные элементы, а табличные. Читаем первый абзац параграфа 17.5 спецификации CSS - https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-layout . Внутренние элементы таблицы образуют прямоугольные блоки с содержимым и границами. У ячеек также имеются внутренние отступы (paddings). Внутренние элементы таблицы не имеют внешних отступов (margins).

Comment: Тут же имеется ввиду задать поля самой табилце, а не самим ячейкам

Comment: Тогда вы должны добавить `.container { margin: 0 -1em; }`. Но это очень плохой способ выравнивания границ таблицы. Горизонтальные `margin` влияют на содержимое и такой способ выравния неизбежно приведет к переполнению, а также возникновению горизонтальных прокруток, когда таблица перестанет помещаться в корневом элементе.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.